# getting 403 (Forbidden) error in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am new to angularjs, i am working on an token based authentication application, i have created a service, what it does when a user's login credentials are correct then it create a token and stored in **cachedToken** which i can access through **getToken()** function. but it does not work in the dashboard page and give object **undefined**, not understand what to do.

my authService.js

```
 var app = angular.module('loginFormApp', [])

 .factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
     var cachedToken;
     return {
         authentication: function (UserName, Password) {
             return $http.post("URL", {
                     'userName': UserName,
                     'password': Password
                 })
                 .then(function (response) {
                         window.location.href = "URL/dashboard.html";
                         cachedToken = response.data.httpHeaders.h5cAuthToken;
                         return cachedToken;
                         //   alert(token);

                     },
                     // Error Handling
                     function (response) {
                         console.log(response.datas);
                     });

         },
         getToken: function() {
             alert(cachedToken);
             return cachedToken;

         }

     }
 })

 .controller('loginFormCtrl', function ($scope, AuthService) {
     $scope.loginCall = function () {
         AuthService.authentication($scope.loginId, $scope.password).then(function (token) {
             AuthService.getToken();            
         });


     };
 });
```

my dashboard.html

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['loginFormApp']);
        app.controller('dashboardFormCtrl', function($scope, $http, AuthService) {
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'h5cAuthToken': AuthService.getToken(),
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                }
            };
            //alert(config.headers.h5cAuthToken);

            $http.get("URL", config).success(function(data) {

                $scope.dashboardData = data;

            });


        });

    </script>
```

error :

```
Navigated to URL/dashboard.html
dashboard.html:126 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7BdashboardData.singleResult.userProfile.memberPhotoPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
dashboard.html:216 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7Bactivityitem.participantPicPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
dashboard.html:289 GET http://192.168.1.148:2000/angular/%7B%7BchallengeItem.participantPicPath%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js:1'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
angular.js:10765 GET http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/dashboardearnfit/fetch 403 (Forbidden)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765r @ angular.js:10558g @ angular.js:10268(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14792$eval @ angular.js:16052$digest @ angular.js:15870$apply @ angular.js:16160(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1679e @ angular.js:4523c @ angular.js:1677yc @ angular.js:1697Zd @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013b @ angular.js:3057If @ angular.js:3346d @ angular.js:3334
```

Comment: In the log, what's the object undefined you're getting? Is the HTTP Request made?

Comment: Seems to me you don't use `ng-src` for the images. For the 403 error a good idea is to check the path of the request (ip address? port?) because it indicates you have no permissions to access that path.

Comment: @MuliYulzary, it's not get the token in dashboard.html page through 'h5cAuthToken': AuthService.getToken(), do you know why it's not getting the token